# How to create random number in swift 2

Tags: swift2, xcode7

i am new to swift two and was wondering how to make a random number generator.
it needs to do numbers from 1 - 5. I have tried Int(arc4random(6)) but i don't think it works in swift 2 because i always get an error message.

thank you so much for anyone that helps.

Comment: I made a search for "swift 2 random number" on google and the first four results had the correct answer. You should try searching before asking. I think even bing could had found that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it:

```
    // +1 to start from 1 and not 0
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(5) + 1)

    if randomNumber % 2 == 0 {
        print("\(randomNumber) is an even number")
    }else{
        print("\(randomNumber) is an odd number")
    }
```

Comment: thank you, i did do a google search but Xcode gave me errors i think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you want, you can do `let number = arc4random_uniform(6)` in Swift.

Comment: note to Matt Lewin answer: at least import Darwin is necessary, because the function is not part of swift standard library. arc4random() has no arguments at all

Comment: You'll likely never need import Darwin, as it'll be included in import Foundation or import UIKit. I do apologize for my original answer, I missed the part of your Q where you wanted a minimum value of 1.